# Meaning of "She is an open book in her own cipher"

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

My friend did post in Instagram "She is an open book in her own cipher".

But I did not understand its meaning.

What is its meaning?

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. What does your research indicate it might mean? What is your best guess?

Comment: @rajah9 I know the meaning of each word separately. But I don't know as a whole.

Comment: i.e. If you can understand her secret language than she is an open book. I guess.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn’t make sense.

Comment: @Xanne I don't know why this is off topic. I have asked similar question previously. Can you please provide the meaning of above statement of question instead, that would be really helpful.

Answer (score 3):

**An Open Book**

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/an%20open%20book) defines this as

> a person or thing that is easy to learn about and understand

**Cipher**

M-W defines a [cipher](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cipher) as:

> 2b: a message in code

The sentence is an oxymoron. It probably means that she should be easy to understand, but you can only understand her life through her cipher, making her difficult to decipher and understand.